# How to set ButterKnife to make line by line codestyle?

Tags: android-studio

Right how i'm looking on project, where is ButterKnife annotations seems line by line(don't look on red MapView):

[image]

I'm trying to do it same way(i very like this style), but when i press alt + ctrl + l(reformate code), it's all breaking down:

[image]

I don't believe that previos developer make this binds order by hands, i think he using something.

Can you give me the cue how to make this ButterKnife codestyle in my project, or how to prevent breaking my order when i using code reformate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **not wrap** your *field annotations* in new line then change it from settings like following steps:

1. Go to **File -> Settings** *(Ctrl+Alt+S)*:
2. In the Editor section, Go to **Code Style -> Java** *(As you're using Java, do for Kotlin in it if using)*
3. Go to **Wrapping And Braces** tab, find **Field annotations** and select *Do not wrap* from drop-down.

**See attached image** :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your Android Studio code style, not on ButterKnife. It can be changed in Settings. You have to modify style so annotations and declarations could be on one line